# Deploying Java / JSP / Struts 2 web app on IIS on Windows server

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, struts2

My client has a Windows Server and wants me to deploy a Java / JSP / Struts 2 based web application on the windows server that has IIS as an application server that is installed.

My web application uses MySQL 5.5 for storage of data.

I easily host my web applications on Linux based servers with Apache Tomcat installed on them.

Pls guide me on how do I proceed in case of windows server with IIS?

Comment: You should use a web server that supports servlets spec. check struts 2 doc that provide a minimum web application requirement your web server should acknowledge.

Comment: Thank you Roman. So you mean I cannot be using IIS? I think I should be good installing Tomcat on it and deploying my webapps into tomcat.

Comment: Just wanted to know if some plugins with IIS would support such applications, so that I can avoid additional installation of web servers like tomcat.

Comment: If even such plugin exists they don't have a direct Java/Servlets support. There's a Tomcat binary for Windows, Apache WS. Why do you need IIS?

Comment: This is what exactly I wanted to know. Was sticking to IIS because there are already a few other web pages running on the IIS. Anyways thanks again for your time. Will work on getting Apache WS installed on the host.

Comment: You need to specify different listening ports for IIS and Tomcat.

Comment: Yes MGorgon. That is something important that I need to take care of.

Comment: First hit on google: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Answer (score 1):

`IIS` is a web server, it is **not java application server**.

Normally `IIS` can not execute `Servlets` and `Java Server Pages (JSPs)`, **configuring IIS to use the `JK ISAPI redirector plugin`** will let `IIS` send servlet and JSP requests to Tomcat (and this way, serve them to clients).

You can use IIS as proxy to tomcat.

Please read this link for configuring `IIS` to use the `JK ISAPI redirector plugin`.

[How to configure IIS with tomcat?](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html)

### How does it work??

1. The IIS-Tomcat redirector is an IIS plugin (filter + extension), IIS load the redirector plugin and calls its filter function for each in-coming request.
2. The filter then tests the request URL against a list of URI-paths held inside uriworkermap.properties, If the current request matches one of the entries in the list of URI-paths, the filter transfer the request to the extension.
3. The extension collects the request parameters and forwards them to the appropriate worker using the defined protocol like ajp13 .
4. The extension collects the response from the worker and returns it to the browser.